# Do browsers always use the cached version of a page with .html extension?

Tags: php, html, refresh

I have a web page written in pure HTML (with a .html extension). Whenever I edit it and push "Refresh" in my browser, the page does not get updated. However, if I change the extension to .php this problem does not occur. Could someone explain to me what's going on?

Comment: You are saving those edits, correct?  What web server are you using?

Comment: "You are saving those edits, correct?" lol

Comment: I'm using a free host. That might be the problem.

Comment: @GaVrA Troubleshooting step 1: Is it plugged in? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try hitting CTRL + Refresh or CTRL + F5. This should do a hard refresh and reload new content. This is only to do with **Browser caching** though.

There is also a specific meta tag which you can use to disable caching in the browser - see http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html

Also, you can check your host and see if you're using static content caching on the server.

For example - you can tell IIS to cache specific files for a certain amount of time using an Expires header.

Answer (score 1):

Most web servers are configured to automatically add some headers to pages served by php:

```
Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma:         no-cache
```

This prevents the browser from caching the page.  In order to force a reload of a page, hold down shift and hit the reload button.